# Can value iteration and policy iteration have multiple solutions?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Do these functions have only one global optima to which they always converge(if they can converge) or are there multiple optimas?

Comment: Could you add a little bit more background to your question, such as whether you are considering the tabular forms of these dynamic programming techniques only? If not, can you give some more details to help narrow things down? Also, an MDP can easily have multiple optimal solutions that are all of equal value (e.g. calling "Heads" or "Tails" for tossing a coin). Are you asking about that, or are you more concerned with the algorithm getting "stuck" in a local optimum and not finding a true global optimum policy?

Comment: I am more concerned about the local optima.

Comment: Please clarify more about the scenario you are concerned about. Are you looking at the theory for tabular dynamic programming (without any function approximation, such as neural networks)?

Comment: I dont have any specific model in mind. I just want to know if it is possible for Q-Learning(with or without NeuralNets) to have multiple solutions because if that is true, I will have to implement some kind of random restarts after convergence.

Comment: Your question title is about value iteration and policy iteration, not Q-learning - you should probably change that. In tabular learners, eventual convergence to an optimal policy is guaranteed. When you add estimators then there are some ways to get bounds on estimate. But a neural net is a neural net - it doesn't have convergence guarantees anyway, and the situation is complicated. I think you need to put more details about what you are doing into the question in order to get a useful answer.